# Username of file uploader is not displayed

Tags: javascript, php, html, mysql, file-upload

I made a parents teachers upload *(It also contains the username to be displayed when I upload a file)* I copied the same thing into another file and did some edits according to the db and the file uploads correctly but the **user_id is 0** [ there is no record with **user_id 0**]. This is my problem I would request someone to please provide me some help.

Sorry this is a huge code but wanted to show the working file.The file which I contain the problem is at the bottom.
thanks

par_upload.php

```
    <html>
<title>File|Mgr</title>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
    <meta name="description" content="">
<link href="globe.png" rel="shortcut icon">
<?php
date_default_timezone_set("Asia/Calcutta");
//echo date_default_timezone_get();
?>


<?php
   $conn = mysqli_connect("localhost","root","","stu_supervision");
 session_start();
// Check connection
if (mysqli_connect_errno())
  {
  echo "Failed to connect to MySQL: " . mysqli_connect_error();
  }

if(isset($_POST['submit'])!="")
{
  $name=$_FILES['photo']['name'];
  $size=$_FILES['photo']['size'];
  $type=$_FILES['photo']['type'];
  $temp=$_FILES['photo']['tmp_name'];
  $date = date('Y-m-d H:i:s');
  //$caption1=$_POST['caption'];
 // $link=$_POST['link'];
  $file_error = $_FILES['photo']['error'];


    $file_ext = explode('.', $name);
    $file_ext = strtolower(end($file_ext));

    //$allowed  = array('jpg', 'jpeg');
    $allowed  = array('pdf');

    if(in_array($file_ext, $allowed))
    {
        if($file_error === 0)
        {
             if(file_exists('files/' . $name))
                {
                   // die('<script type="text/javascript">alert("File with that name already exists.");location.replace("index.php")</script>');   

                   die('<script type="text/javascript">alert("File with that name already exists.");location.replace("par_upload.php")</script>');   
                }


            //if($size <= 2097152) {




    //--------WHEN UPLOADING FILE, A UNIQUE ID IS GENERATED IN FILES FOLDER THRU 1ST METHOD -------------------
               /// $file_name_new = uniqid('', true) . '.' . $file_ext; 
              //  $file_destination = 'files/' . $file_name_new;  
                $file_destination = 'files/'.$name ;
                move_uploaded_file($temp, $file_destination);

                $query=mysqli_query($conn,"INSERT INTO upload (name,date,par_id) VALUES ('$name','$date','".$_SESSION['par_id']."')");


                if($query){
               // header("location:index.php");
                    header("location:par_upload.php");
                }
                else{
                die(mysql_error());
                }
    }

        }
     else
      { 
        echo '<script language="javascript">';
        echo 'alert(" SORRY! YOU ARE ONLY ABLE TO UPLOAD PDF FILES")';
        echo '</script>';
      }
}

?>





<html>
<body>

<link href="css/bootstrap.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" media="screen">
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="css/DT_bootstrap.css">
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="css/font-awesome.css">
<link rel="stylesheet" href="css/bootstrap.min.css">
<link rel="stylesheet" href="font-awesome/css/font-awesome.min.css"/>
</head>
<script src="js/jquery.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script src="js/bootstrap.js" type="text/javascript"></script>

<script type="text/javascript" charset="utf-8" language="javascript" src="js/jquery.dataTables.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" charset="utf-8" language="javascript" src="js/DT_bootstrap.js"></script>
<?php include('dbcon.php'); ?>
<style>
.table tr th{

    border:#eee 1px solid;

    position:relative;
    #font-family:"Times New Roman", Times, serif;
    font-size:12px;
    text-transform:uppercase;
    }
    table tr td{

    border:#eee 1px solid;
    color:#000;
    position:relative;
    #font-family:"Times New Roman", Times, serif;
    font-size:12px;

    text-transform:uppercase;
    }

#wb_Form1
{
   background-color: #00BFFF;
   border: 0px #000 solid;

}
#photo
{
   border: 1px #A9A9A9 solid;
   background-color: #00BFFF;
   color: #fff;
   font-family:Arial;
   font-size: 20px;
}
    </style>
                        Hi <?=$_SESSION['sess_user'];?>! <br><br>
                            <table cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" border="0" class="table table-bordered">     
            <tr><td><form enctype="multipart/form-data"  action="" id="wb_Form1" name="form" method="post">     
                    <input type="file" name="photo" id="photo" accept="application/pdf"  required="required"></td>



                    <td><input type="submit" class="btn btn-danger" value="SUBMIT" name="submit">
            </form> <strong>SUBMIT HERE</strong></tr></td></table>
                 <div class="col-md-18">
    <div class="container-fluid" style="margin-top:0px;">
   <div class = "row">
        <div class="panel panel-default">
            <div class="panel-body">
                <div class="table-responsive">


                        <form method="post" action="delete.php" >
                     <table cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" border="0" class="table table-condensed" id="example">

                            <thead>

                                <tr>

                                    <th>ID</th>
                                    <th>FILE NAME</th>
                                   <th>Date</th>
                                    <th>username</th>

                <!--    <th>Download</th>   -->
                <!--    <th>Remove</th> -->


                                </tr>
                            </thead>
                            <tbody>

                        <?php 
                            $query=mysqli_query($conn, "select * from `upload` left join `par` on par.par_id=upload.par_id  ORDER BY id DESC ");

                               // $query=mysqli_query($conn, "select * from `upload` left join `par` on par.par_id=upload.par_id where p_username = '".$_SESSION['par_id']."' ORDER BY id DESC ");
                                if($query === false){
    throw new Exception(mysql_error($conn));
}
                            while($row=mysqli_fetch_array($query)){
                            $id=$row['id'];
                            $name=$row['name'];
                            $date=$row['date'];
                            $username = $row['p_username'];
                            ?>
                                        <tr>

                                         <td><?php echo $row['id'] ?></td>
                                         <td><?php echo $row['name'] ?></td>
                                         <td><?php echo $row['date'] ?></td>
                                             <td> <?php echo $row['p_username'] ?></td>
   <!-- <td>
                <a href="download.php?filename=<?php echo $name;?>" title="click to download">VIEW <!--<span class="glyphicon glyphicon-paperclip" style="font-size:20px; color:blue"></span>-->
                <!-- </a>   </td>   --> 
            <!--    <td>
                <a onclick="return confirm('Are you sure you want to delete this file? ')" href="delete.php?del=<?php //echo $row['id']?>"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-trash" style="font-size:20px; color:red"></span></a>
                </td>   --> 



                                </tr>

                                  <?php }
                                ?>
                            </tbody>
                        </table>
                           </div>

</form>
      </div>
        </div>
        </div>
    </div>



</body>
</html>


----------------------------------------------
par_upoad_view.php

<html>
<title>File|Mgr</title>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
    <meta name="description" content="">
<link href="globe.png" rel="shortcut icon">
<?php
//date_default_timezone_set("Asia/Calcutta");
//echo date_default_timezone_get();

?>


<?php
  /* $conn = mysqli_connect("localhost","root","","stu_supervision");
 session_start();
// Check connection
if (mysqli_connect_errno())
  {
  echo "Failed to connect to MySQL: " . mysqli_connect_error();
  }

if(isset($_POST['submit'])!="")
{
  $name=$_FILES['photo']['name'];
  $size=$_FILES['photo']['size'];
  $type=$_FILES['photo']['type'];
  $temp=$_FILES['photo']['tmp_name'];
  $date = date('Y-m-d H:i:s');
  //$caption1=$_POST['caption'];
 // $link=$_POST['link'];
  $file_error = $_FILES['photo']['error'];


    $file_ext = explode('.', $name);
    $file_ext = strtolower(end($file_ext));

    //$allowed  = array('jpg', 'jpeg');
    $allowed  = array('pdf');

    if(in_array($file_ext, $allowed))
    {
        if($file_error === 0)
        {
             if(file_exists('files/' . $name))
                {
                   // die('<script type="text/javascript">alert("File with that name already exists.");location.replace("index.php")</script>');   

                   die('<script type="text/javascript">alert("File with that name already exists.");location.replace("par_upload.php")</script>');   
                }


            //if($size <= 2097152) {




    //--------WHEN UPLOADING FILE, A UNIQUE ID IS GENERATED IN FILES FOLDER THRU 1ST METHOD -------------------
               /// $file_name_new = uniqid('', true) . '.' . $file_ext; 
              //  $file_destination = 'files/' . $file_name_new;  
                $file_destination = 'files/'.$name ;
                move_uploaded_file($temp, $file_destination);

                $query=mysqli_query($conn,"INSERT INTO upload (name,date,par_id) VALUES ('$name','$date','".$_SESSION['par_id']."')");


                if($query){
               // header("location:index.php");
                    header("location:par_upload.php");
                }
                else{
                die(mysql_error());
                }
    }

        }
     else
      { 
        echo '<script language="javascript">';
        echo 'alert(" SORRY! YOU ARE ONLY ABLE TO UPLOAD PDF FILES")';
        echo '</script>';
      }
}
 */           
?>





<html>
<body>

<link href="css/bootstrap.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" media="screen">
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="css/DT_bootstrap.css">
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="css/font-awesome.css">
<link rel="stylesheet" href="css/bootstrap.min.css">
<link rel="stylesheet" href="font-awesome/css/font-awesome.min.css"/>
</head>
<script src="js/jquery.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script src="js/bootstrap.js" type="text/javascript"></script>

<script type="text/javascript" charset="utf-8" language="javascript" src="js/jquery.dataTables.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" charset="utf-8" language="javascript" src="js/DT_bootstrap.js"></script>
<?php include('dbcon.php'); ?>
<style>
.table tr th{

    border:#eee 1px solid;

    position:relative;
    #font-family:"Times New Roman", Times, serif;
    font-size:12px;
    text-transform:uppercase;
    }
    table tr td{

    border:#eee 1px solid;
    color:#000;
    position:relative;
    #font-family:"Times New Roman", Times, serif;
    font-size:12px;

    text-transform:uppercase;
    }

#wb_Form1
{
   background-color: #00BFFF;
   border: 0px #000 solid;

}
#photo
{
   border: 1px #A9A9A9 solid;
   background-color: #00BFFF;
   color: #fff;
   font-family:Arial;
   font-size: 20px;
}
    </style>
                            <!--    <table cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" border="0" class="table table-bordered">     
            <tr><td><form enctype="multipart/form-data"  action="" id="wb_Form1" name="form" method="post">     
                    <input type="file" name="photo" id="photo" accept="application/pdf"  required="required"></td>



                    <td><input type="submit" class="btn btn-danger" value="SUBMIT" name="submit">
            </form> <strong>SUBMIT HERE</strong></tr></td></table>
             -->




                 <div class="col-md-18">
    <div class="container-fluid" style="margin-top:0px;">
   <div class = "row">
        <div class="panel panel-default">
            <div class="panel-body">
                <div class="table-responsive">


                        <form method="post" action="delete.php" >
                     <table cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" border="0" class="table table-condensed" id="example">

                            <thead>

                                <tr>

                                    <th>ID</th>
                                    <th>FILE NAME</th>
                                   <th>Date</th>
                                    <th>username</th>

                <th>Download</th>
                <th>Remove</th>


                                </tr>
                            </thead>
                            <tbody>

                        <?php 
                            $query=mysqli_query($conn, "select * from `upload` left join `par` on par.par_id=upload.par_id  ORDER BY id DESC ");

                               // $query=mysqli_query($conn, "select * from `upload` left join `par` on par.par_id=upload.par_id where p_username = '".$_SESSION['par_id']."' ORDER BY id DESC ");
                                if($query === false){
    throw new Exception(mysql_error($conn));
}
                            while($row=mysqli_fetch_array($query)){
                            $id=$row['id'];
                            $name=$row['name'];
                            $date=$row['date'];
                            $username = $row['p_username'];
                            ?>
                                        <tr>

                                         <td><?php echo $row['id'] ?></td>
                                         <td><?php echo $row['name'] ?></td>
                                         <td><?php echo $row['date'] ?></td>
                                             <td> <?php echo $row['p_username'] ?></td>
    <td>
                <a href="download.php?filename=<?php echo $name;?>" title="click to download">VIEW <!--<span class="glyphicon glyphicon-paperclip" style="font-size:20px; color:blue"></span>--></a>
                </td>
                <td>
                <a onclick="return confirm('Are you sure you want to delete this file? ')" href="delete.php?del=<?php echo $row['id']?>"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-trash" style="font-size:20px; color:red"></span></a>
                </td>



                                </tr>

                                  <?php }
                                ?>
                            </tbody>
                        </table>
                           </div>

</form>
      </div>
        </div>
        </div>
    </div>



</body>
</html>
```

---

```
                  ---PROBLEM----
```

[*THE IMG OF THE UPLOAD TABLE AND HOW THE STU_ID IS DISPLAYED WHEN FILE IS UPLOADED IS PLACED HERE](https://i.stack.imgur.com/75suC.png)

[*AN IMG OF THE STUDENT TABLE](https://i.stack.imgur.com/yYfAd.png)

```
 <?php
       $conn = mysqli_connect("localhost","root","","stu_supervision");
     session_start();
    // Check connection
    if (mysqli_connect_errno())
      {
      echo "Failed to connect to MySQL: " . mysqli_connect_error();
      }

    if(isset($_POST['submit'])!="")
    {
      $name=$_FILES['photo']['name'];
      $size=$_FILES['photo']['size'];
      $type=$_FILES['photo']['type'];
      $temp=$_FILES['photo']['tmp_name'];
      $date = date('Y-m-d H:i:s');

      $file_error = $_FILES['photo']['error'];


        $file_ext = explode('.', $name);
        $file_ext = strtolower(end($file_ext));


        $allowed  = array('pdf');

        if(in_array($file_ext, $allowed))
        {
            if($file_error === 0)
            {
                 if(file_exists('files1/' . $name))
                    {

                       die('<script type="text/javascript">alert("File with that name already exists.");location.replace("abc.php")</script>');   
                    }

                    $file_destination = 'files1/'.$name ;
                    move_uploaded_file($temp, $file_destination);

                    $query=mysqli_query($conn,"INSERT INTO upload1 (name,date,stu_id) VALUES ('$name','$date','".$_SESSION['stu_id']."')");


                    if($query){
                        header("location:abc.php");
                    }
                    else{
                    die(mysql_error());
                    }
        }

            }
         else
          { 
            echo '<script language="javascript">';
            echo 'alert(" SORRY! YOU ARE ONLY ABLE TO UPLOAD PDF FILES")';
            echo '</script>';
          }
    }

    ?>
```

Comment: try this first `print_r($_SESSION['stu_id'])` to see if it has your `stu_id`

Comment: @jerome yeah i tried to display the name of the logged-in user and it perfectly displays the name but my problem is when i try to upload, the name of  uploader of the file

Comment: @jerome i did the same thing for the parents teachers upload it works but cant understand whats happening here

Comment: I think what your storing to your table is `stu_id` not the `name`. Based on your query

Comment: Where are you storing user's name in the sql query instead you are storing file name in **$name**.

Comment: @Hp_issei i store the user name in a seperate table

Comment: What I am saying is where is the sql query in which you are storing  users name.

Comment: @jerome yeah i store the stu_id so it could be called from the student table stu_id. i do not have a student with stu_id = 0 but the stu_id in the  upload table is  displayed as 0

Comment: @Hp_issei '".$_SESSION['stu_id']."' the stu id should call the username

Comment: You need another query if you want to display the name using its id.

Comment: @jerome yeah i know and i also know how to do it but the id does not get uploaded correctly inorder to display the name.

Comment: Sorry i'm confused. Can you elaborate your question again?

Comment: @jerome i made a parents teachers upload( it also contains the useraneme to be displayed when i upload a file) i copied the same thinf into another file and did some edits according to the db and the file uploads correctty but the user_id is 0 [ there is no record with user_id 0] this is my problem

Comment: It might be helpful too if you edit your post and add the code where you fetch users(parent/teachers) info and how did you save it to your session. I guess that's where your problem exists

Comment: @jerome i have edited the content pls check if u could provide me  a solution

Comment: @TheKingMaker you dont have `session_start()` at `par_upoad_view.php`

Comment: @jerome it was done purposely. now i set the code so that teachers could upload files it works perfectly but all the problems for the student